# How to set DateComponentFormatter's local other than current?

Tags: swift, nsdate, nsdatecomponentsformatter

**Situation**

I have a function that uses `DateComponentFormatter`'s function `fun string(from: Date, to: Date)` to return a formatted string based on the time difference between two dates and it works perfectly. However **I want to return this formatted string always in English** (currently formatting according to device's local).

**Questions**

How do you set the `DateComponentFormatter`'s local like what you can do with `DateFormatter`'s? If you can't, how would you proceed?

**Code:**

```
import Foundation

func returnRemainingTimeAsString(currentDate: Date, nextDate: Date)->String {

  let dateComponentsFormatter = DateComponentsFormatter()
  dateComponentsFormatter.unitsStyle = DateComponentsFormatter.UnitsStyle.full
  dateComponentsFormatter.allowedUnits = [.day, .hour, .minute, .second]
  dateComponentsFormatter.maximumUnitCount = 1

  let differenceAsString = dateComponentsFormatter.string(from: currentDate, to: nextDate)!

  return differenceAsString
}

let currentDate = Date()
let futureDate = currentDate.addingTimeInterval(3604)
returnRemainingTimeAsString(currentDate: currentDate, nextDate: futureDate)

// prints 1 hour (if devices local is English) or 1 hora (if Spanish),
// and I want it to return always 1 hour.
```

Answer (score 10, accepted):

`DateComponentsFormatter` has a `calendar` property.

Get the current calendar, set its locale and assign the calendar to the formatter.

```
let dateComponentsFormatter = DateComponentsFormatter()
var calendar = Calendar.current
calendar.locale = Locale(identifier: "en_US_POSIX")
dateComponentsFormatter.calendar = calendar
dateComponentsFormatter.unitsStyle = .full
...
```

Comment: What is the locale for ? identifier: "en_US_POSIX"

Comment: @Farhadam `en_US_POSIX` is *a locale that's specifically designed to yield US English results regardless of both user and system preferences*. See [Technical Q&A QA1480](https://developer.apple.com/library/archive/qa/qa1480/_index.html)

Answer (score 1):

For the formatter to show localized strings, you have to specify the supported locales in the target settings.

[image]

If the device’s current locale is one of the locales supported in the target settings, you will get the localized date components without needing to manually set the `calendar` of the formatter. You only need to do that if you want a locale other than the device’s current locale.